# Mysql, how to change the following query to fech each row of a table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an event occurring once a day.  I have 2 tables:

- application
- rating

Basically, each application has an `avg_score` that is given by the average of all the feedbacks given by users that are stored in the table rating in the field score.  I wrote an event that once a day refresh this value:

```
CREATE EVENT MY_DAILY_UPDATE
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2011-07-23 23:30:00'
DO

  UPDATE application
     SET `avg_score`= (SELECT AVG(`score`) as new_score
                         FROM `rating`
                        WHERE `ID_APPLICATION` = 1)      
   WHERE `APPLICATION_ID` = 1
```

It works, but only for the application with ID = 1, cause i wrote it by myself.
Instead i need my query to update the field avg_score for each application in the table application.

So i think i need to change the value 1 with a variable ID (ex WHERE `APPLICATION_ID` = ID_VARIABLE).......and this variable should take the id value of each app in the application table (1,2,3.....4 etc).......but i have no idea about how to change my query.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your sub-query to referrence the values in the outer query.  (This makes it a correlated sub-query.)

```
UPDATE application
SET    avg_score = (
         SELECT AVG(score)
         FROM   rating
         WHERE  ID_APPLICATION = application.APPLICATION_ID
       )
```

Alternatively, as you're doing this for "all values", just join on the sub-query...

```
UPDATE
  application
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT ID_APPLICATION, AVG(score) AS score FROM rating GROUP BY ID_APPLICATION
)
  AS averages
    ON averages.ID_APPLICAITON = application.APPLICATION_ID
SET
  application.avg_score = averages.score
```

Comment: Tnx a lot they both work.......can you just explain me wich is the difference between them (the second one is harder to em to understand cause i'm a sql beginner)? The first one looks much simpler, is the second one faster......wich one do you suggest to use?

Comment: The first uses the sub-query effectively as a scalar-function, and applies it against each row in the source table/query; given an APPLICATION_ID, what's the AVG(score)?  The second uses the sub-query as an inline-view, obtaining the AVG(score) for every ID_APPLICATION, joins it against the application table, and then runs an UPDATE against the results of that join.  I tend to use whatever is faster, and find a way to make it readable/maintainable.  Only if performance is similar will I opt for lower performance to gain readability.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE application
SET `avg_score`= 
    (SELECT AVG(`score`) as new_score
     FROM `rating`
     WHERE `ID_APPLICATION` = `application.APPLICATION_ID`)
```